# How can I fetch the exact value on the database?? On a keyup function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a modal on the receipt of every tenant on a table. The modal has a keyup function to calculate for its bill. and the equation is doing just fine and the fetching of the values to be calculated is also fine, the problem is every time i calculate for the previous electricity consumption it only fetches one value on the database. I have added the code on how i fetch from the database.

here is the Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="receipt<?php echo $value['tenant_id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form  action="save_receipt.php" method="POST">
                <input type = "hidden" class="form-control" name= "id" value = "<?php echo $value['tenant_id'];?>">
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <strong>
                        <div class= "modal-body2"><h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">
                            <strong>Republic of the Philippines<br>Province of Negros Occidental
                            </strong></h3>
                            <h4 class ="text-center"><em>City of Victorias</em></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-center">
                                <strong>OFFICE OF THE MARKET SUPERVISOR
                                </strong>
                            </h4>

                            <br>                            
                            <div class="form-group">    
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name </label>: <?php echo $value['tenant_fname']." ".$value['tenant_mname']." ".$value['tenant_lname'];?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location </label>: Stall No. <?php echo $value['stall_number']." (".$value['stall_floor'];?>)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">SUBJECT </label> :
                                FOR PAYMENT OF ELECTRICAL CONSUMPTION FOR &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;THE PERIOD FROM
                                <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
                                ,TO 
                                <input class = "datepick custom-input1"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">METER NO. </label>: <input type="text" name=""  class = "custom-input"></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">ELECTRIC RATE </label>:<input class = "custom-input3"  value="<?php echo $value['elec_rate']?> per kWh" id= "rate" readonly ></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PRESENT </label>: <input class = "custom-input" name="charges"></input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">PREVIOUS </label>: <input  class = "custom-input" value ="<?php echo $value['charges']?> kWh" id = "previous" readonly> </input> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">TOTAL CONSUMPTION</label>:
                                <input type="text"  class = "custom-input" type="" id="result1" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">AMOUNT </label>: 
                                <input type="text"  class = "custom-input3" type="" id="result" value="" readonly>
                            </div><br>                              
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p class="text-right">APPROVED BY: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    LUDAISY B. FERNANDEZ&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                                    MARKET SUPERVISOR III&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                </button>
                <!-- <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> -->
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Print Receipt</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the script:

```
<script>
$('input[name="charges"]').on('change paste keyup', function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    console.log(a);
    var b = $('input#rate').val().replace('per kWh', '');
    var c = $('input#previous').val().replace('kWh', '');
    var subtotal = parseFloat(a - c);
    var total = parseFloat(subtotal * b);
    console.log(total);
    $('input#result1').val(subtotal);
    $('input#result').val(total);

});
$('.close-modal, .modal-fade').click(function(){
    $('input#result1').val('');
    $('input#result').val('');
    $('input#charges').val('');
});
```

i have attached a example image of the receipt.
every time i input the current electricity consumption 
it will automatically subrtract to the previous electricity consumption for the total consumption 
and the total consumption will be multiplied to the rate for the amount to be paid.
as you can see the total consumption is giving a wrong answer because it is only fetching 1 value on the database.

[image]

here is how i fetch from the database:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
          <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Tenant</th>
                <th>Stall Code</th>
                <th>Previous Readings</th>
                <th>Receipt</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tenant 
                LEFT JOIN stall ON stall.stall_id = tenant.stall_id
                LEFT JOIN rent ON rent.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
                        LEFT JOIN receipt ON receipt.tenant_id = tenant.tenant_id
                          LEFT JOIN rate ON rate.rate_id = tenant.rate_id
                WHERE rent.rent_status = ? AND rate.rate_id = ?
                ";
                $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array(1,1));
                $fetch = $query->fetchAll();

              foreach ($fetch as $key => $value) { ?>
               <tr>
                <td><?=$value['tenant_fname']." ".$value['tenant_mname']." ".$value['tenant_lname'];?></td>
                <td><?=$value['stall_number'];?></td>
                <td><?=$value['charges'];?></td>
                 <td class = "center" style = "text-align:center;">
                   <a href = "#receipt<?php echo $value['tenant_id'];?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-outline btn-xs btn-primary"> Make Receipt
                   </a>
                 </td>
              </tr> 
                <?php include 'receipt_modal.php';?>              
              <?php }?>

            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: How are you fetching data from the database? Show code...

Comment: @Valkyrurr i have added the fetching code from the database

Comment: Since you are using JOIN on your query try to indicate the exact data that you are getting instead of getting all the columns using *. There is a possibility that there 2 same column and you might not getting the correct one. For example stall.stall_number from table stall etc...